# Ruby Kata Integer conversion troubleshoot

Tags: ruby

I'm solving this ruby kata. Essentially what the code does is to output an integer with five digits.
Example:

```
5 = 00005
12 = 00012
12345 = 12345
00001234 = 012345
```

Here is my code:

```
def solution(value) #00001204
  string_value = value.to_s
  if string_value.length <= 5
    amount_of_zeros = "0" * (string_value.length - 5).abs
    puts "Value is #{amount_of_zeros}" + "#{string_value}"
  else
    start_of_characters = 5 - string_value.length  #-3
    puts "Value is " +  string_value[-1..start_of_characters]
  end
end
```

Everything works fine until I place `00001204`. For some reason I get the output `00644`. I tried using `binding.pry` to see what was going on and my number gets converted into `644` from the start. Why is it doing that? The docs don't mention anything about it. I don't how to fix this because on the first line of my method it already turns into `644`. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ruby, numbers that are 0-prefixed are interpreted as octal. When you pass `00001204` to your method, ruby is assuming that you want the number interpreted as octal. 1204<sub>8</sub> = 644<sub>10</sub>.

```
644.to_s 8 
=> "1204"
01204.to_s 10
=> "644"
```

Check out the [Ruby documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Numbers) on literals.

Comment: Thanks @Zajn. Ruby wouldn't happen to have a method that changes the octal to decimal would it?

Comment: You can use `to_s(base)`, where base is the number-base you want to convert to. So `01204.to_s(10)` would yield `"644"`.

Comment: In *many* languages, 0-prefixed numbers are treated as octal. This isn't limited to Ruby. `0x08 # => 8`, `010 # => 8`, `8 # => 8`, `0b00001000 # => 8`, which are hexadecimal, octal, decimal and binary representations of the same number `8`.

Answer (score 0):

as Zajn said it is due to it being interpreted as octal.

You can also use `.to_i` to force it to be an integer.

```
>> 000000001204
=> 644
>> "000000001204".to_i
=> 1204
```

Also take a look at string formatting with % if you just want to output it, since it can clean up your code a lot

```
>> "%05d" % "000001204".to_i
=> "01204"
```